# Finding global maximum and minimum

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

i have this function $f (x, y) = - 2x^2 - 3y^2 + 4xy + 4x - 10y$.
in the compact set D bounded by the lines $x = 0$, $y = 0$ and $x + y = - 6$. I have to find global maximum and minimum. My problem is that I can't understand what to do with these $x = 0$ and $y = 0$.

I found the global maximum and minimum  with the equation $x + y= -6$. I found y = -6-x and substituted into the main function $f (x, -6-x ) = - 2x^2 - 3y^2 + 4xy + 4x - 10y$. The result is $-9x^2 - 36^x -48$. I found the derivative $-18y-36 = 0$ and got that the global extremums of the function are $f (-2, 4) = -136$ and $f (4, -2)= - 40$.

But I don't know how to use that $x = 0$ and $y = 0$. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: What you have calculated (I did not check your calculations) are not the extrema of $f$ (on $D$) but those of its restriction to one side of the triangle $D.$ This will be useful but is not sufficient. Apply [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160874/how-to-find-extrema-on-a-triangle/912671#912671). I.e. calculate similarly the extrema of the restriction to the 2 other sides, and the value of $f$ at critical points in the interior of the triangle. A critical point is a point where $\partial f/\partial x=\partial f/\partial y=0.$

Comment: Please [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $D = \{x\le 0 \cap y\le 0 \cap x + y + 6 \ge 0 \} $ the lagrangian reads:

$$
L(x,y,\lambda,s) = -2x^2 - 3 y^2 + 4 x y + 4 x - 10 y + \lambda_1(x + y + 6 -s_1^2)+\lambda_2(x+s_2^2)+\lambda_3(y+s_3^2)
$$

The stationary points of this lagrangian are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \cases{
\lambda_1+\lambda_2-4 x+4 y+4\\
\lambda_1+\lambda_3+4 x-6 y-10\\
x+y+6-s_1^2\\
x+s_2^2\\
y+s_3^2\\
\lambda_1s_1\\
\lambda_2 s_2\\
\lambda_3s_3
}
$$

Using the fact $\lambda_is_i = 0$ and after solving the $2^3$ possible linear systems, we arrive at

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
f & x & y & \lambda_1 & \lambda_2 & \lambda_3 & s_1^2&s_2^2&s_3^2\\
 -96 & -6 & 0 & -28 & 0 & 62 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\
 -48 & 0 & -6 & -26 & 46 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4 & 10 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{25}{3} & 0 & -\frac{5}{3} & 0 & \frac{8}{3} & 0 & \frac{13}{3} & 0 & \frac{5}{3} \\
 \frac{97}{9} & -\frac{23}{9} & -\frac{31}{9} & -\frac{4}{9} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{23}{9} & \frac{31}{9} \\
 11 & -2 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Here when $s_i = 0$ indicates that the corresponding restriction is actuating otherwise, the solution is interior to this restriction. Now the last step is the qualification of those points...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is that I haven't study this method yet. We have to resolve this task with derivatives.